# Chamando action com AJAX, porém não retorna alert para view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, entity-framework, razor

No textbox `Ticket`, no evento `onChange()` eu chamo o AJAX abaixo:

```
$('#Ticket').on('change', function () {
var tkt = this.value;                
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("VerificaTicket", "Oc")',
        data: { 'tkt': tkt },
        type: "post",
        cache: false
    });
 });
```

Chamando a action abaixo:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VerificaTicket(int tkt)
    {
        Oc oc = db.Ocs.Find(tkt);
        if (oc != null)
        {
            ViewBag.IdStatus = new SelectList(db.Status, "IdStatus", "Descricao", oc.IdStatus);
            ViewBag.IdEmpresa = new SelectList(db.Empresas, "IdEmpresa", "Apelido");
            ViewBag.IdFornecedor = new SelectList(db.Fornecedors, "IdFornecedor", "Apelido");
            ViewBag.IdFaturamento = new SelectList(db.Faturamentoes, "IdFaturamento", "Apelido");
            ViewBag.IdEntrega = new SelectList(db.Entregas, "IdEntrega", "Apelido");
            ViewBag.IdProdutos = new SelectList(db.Produtos, "IdProdutos", "Descricao");                
            ViewBag.TicketExiste = "Sim";
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Oc");                
        }
        return this.View();
    }
```

Na view `Create` eu verifico:

```
@if (@ViewBag.TicketExiste == "Sim") {
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Ticket já existe!");
</script>
}
```

acompanhando o breakpoint, até passa no **`if`** do `alert`, mas não executa, não sei o que acontece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora você esteja chamando o método por AJAX, não existe nenhum processamento que receba o retorno do seu redirect. Se o propósito desse action é apenas verificar se o ticket já existe, sugiro que você altere o retorno para JSON e trate no javascript.

```
$('#Ticket').on('change', function () {
    var tkt = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("VerificaTicket", "Oc")',
        data: { 'tkt': tkt },
        type: "post",
        cache: false
    }).success(function (json) {
        if (json.ticketExiste) { //aqui verifica se existe o ticket e mostra o alert
            alert("Ticket já existe!"); 
        }
    });
 });
```

No seu controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VerificaTicket(int tkt)
    {
        bool ticketExiste = false;
        Oc oc = db.Ocs.Find(tkt);
        if (oc != null)
        {
            ticketExiste = true;
        }
        return Json(new { ticketExiste });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que quando a requisição é feita por ajax em um método que retorna um é  ActionResult/PartialViewResult é retornado o objeto e não aquele HTML que é gerado quando se é feita uma requisição normal(por url).
Para resolver esse problema basta mudar o tipo do retorno para JsonResult e retornar o objeto/valor que você deseja.